# Misunderstand how a destructor works?

Tags: c++, class, object

**classy.h**

```
struct Stack{ 
    int *arr;
    int numElements;
    int capacity;
};

class Point { 

private: 
 Stack *newStack;
public: 
  Point (int cap); 
  int returncap (); 
  ~Point(); 
};
```

I don't think the problem is the h file but rather the one of the two cc files

**classy.cc**

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include "classy.h"

    using namespace std;

    Point::Point(int cap){
        newStack = new Stack;
        newStack->numElements = 0;
        newStack->arr = new int [cap];
        if(newStack->arr == NULL) {
        newStack->capacity = 0;
        }
        else {
        newStack->capacity = cap;
        }
    }

    Point::~Point(){ 
        delete newStack->arr;
        delete newStack;
    } 

    int Point::returncap() {
        return newStack->capacity;
    }
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "classy.h"

using namespace std;


int main() { 
  int x;
  cout << "Please insert cap: "<< endl;
  cin >> x;
  Point p (x); 
  cout << p.returncap();
  p.~Point(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Am I calling the destructor wrong or is it my implementation of it? or is their some point I am missing? Essentially  get a memory map before the program quits.

Comment: You're not supposed to call the destructor explicitly and you shouldn't be using pointers at all here (use a `std::vector<int>` and a `Stack` instead of pointers), but when you do, you have to match square brackets on `new` and `delete`.

Comment: If you allocate with `new[]` you need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: Sorry forgetting the [] on delete is a bad habit of mine

Comment: @Pipsydoodles - Better habit is to use STL

Comment: I see you just edited your post to fix the problem... I think it's better not to do that, as it's confusing to people who now see this thread and wonder what the Answers are talking about.

Comment: @MattMcNabb good point and my bad reinserted incorrect line.

Comment: @Pipsydoodles - rolled back - Add summat onto the end of the post otherwise the comments/answers will not make sense

Comment: @EdHeal I am sure it is, but, I haven't had the opportunity to learn about? STL yet.

Comment: @Pipsydoodles - There is no time like the present

Comment: The destructor will get called at scope exit here. You're calling it explicitly. So it will actually get called twice. So you're double freeing memory ect. The ability to call a destructor in c++ is powerful, and necessary sometimes. But here, let scope exit handle it for you like it's designed to do.

Comment: Still don't see why Stack couldn't manage its own memory. Give it ctor and dtor and let it manage internal representation how it sees fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong, in main():

```
p.~Point();
```

In C++ you almost never need to call destructors explicitly.  Instead, they are called "automatically" when an "automatic" (stack, the default type of allocation) variable goes out of scope, or when you call `delete` on something allocated with `new`.  The only time you would invoke a destructor explicitly is when you used "placement new" to construct the object explicitly...and that is something most programmers never do.

Remove the line above and your code should work better.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 delete newStack->arr;
```

should be

```
delete[] newStack->arr;
```

and erase this line

```
p.~Point();
```

Besides if `new` returns NULL (try nullptr) you are really up a certain creek without a certain device

Answer (score 0):

You need not to call the destructor p.~Point(); yourself. It will be automatically called after the end of that class variable's scope.